# React router not working in full refresh the page in apache server

Tags: reactjs

I have created a new application in my local environment. After completed my application, I was trying to run the build files in apache server. Everything is working fine as expected. After navigating the menu, If I click the refresh button the page is goes not found.

I am using browser router for this and I don't to use hash router.

Could you please help anyone to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

This is my env file

```
PUBLIC_URL=/crud
```

This is my Htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule . /index.html [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: Make sure all the routes are handled in Apache too. React router manipulates browser history without making server calls. If you refresh the page it's served from Apache so need to handle all routes in server too

Comment: I have added this in htaccess but still not working